# async true and callback once all completes

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I am using the below ajax call to read a json and display them in a HTML table. number of records returned is random and would like to show a message once all the records have been returned with a message on the screen?

If I do `async:false`, it does not update the DOM and if I change it to `async:true`, the DOM updates however do not know if all the ajax requests are completed.

Any suggestions?

`code`

```
function getData(){
    $.ajax({
        async:      false, 
        type:       'GET',
            dataType:   'json',
        contentType:    'application/json',
        url: serverURL,

        success: function(data){
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
               console.log(value.id);
               AddRowTotable(value);
            });

        },
        error: function(data, status, jqXHR){
            console.log("Error");
            retstatus = status;
        }
        }
    });
}


 function AddRowTotable(rowData) {
        var row = $("<tr />")
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.id + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.name + "</td>"));
        $("#dataTable").append(row); 

    }
```

Comment: how many requests do you have?

Comment: Yeah, how are you supposed to know when all the ajax requests are completed? And what does that have to do with `async`?

Comment: you need to show more code. How is this being used, what does AddRowTotable do?

Comment: When do you call this AJAX?

Comment: thanks so much. I've added the code to the original question. I have a button which calls the getData() function to make the REST API call and populated the table in the HTML. sometimes i get more records and it does not show up as the records arrive. if do 'async:true', then the table updates however would like to show an alert or text once all data is fetched.